# Confusion in 2 diff Formulae for Converting a normal dist to standard normal dist

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, standard-error

I just watched 2 different tutorials and there were 2 different formulas used

1.Z=(X(Bar) - mu )/Standard Deviation

2.Z=(X(Bar) - mu )/Standard Error

Please let me know what is the difference, and which one is correct ?

Thanks

Comment: by the way i was calculating the power of null hypothesis test

Comment: Standard deviation, not error.

Comment: any difference ?

Comment: Perhaps a point of confusion too is that the standard error is the special fancy name for the estimated standard deviation of the sample mean $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i$. Any time you have same estimator $\mathbf{b}$ you call its estimated standard deviation a `"standard error."

Comment: Thanks, U may vote up my question though :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation to transform a normal variate into a standard normal variate is

\begin{equation}
z_i - \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})}{s},
\end{equation} 
using sample-based estimate notation, where $\bar{x}$ is the average of $x$ and $s$ is the standard deviation.  When using population-based parameter notation, the transform is given as
\begin{equation}
z_i - \frac{(x_i - \mu)}{\sigma}, 
\end{equation} 
where $\mu$ is the average of $x$ and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.